# Separating string on each character and putting it in an array

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm pulling a string from a MySQL database containing all ID's from friends in this format:

> **5+6+12+33+1+9+**

Now, whenever i have to add a friend it's simple, I just take the the string and add whatever ID and a "+". My problem lies with separating all the ID's and putting it in an array. I'm currently using this method

```
string InputString = "5+6+12+33+1+9+";

 string CurrentID = string.Empty;
 List<string> AllIDs = new List<string>();
 for (int i = 0; i < InputString.Length; i++)
 {
       if (InputString.Substring(i,1) != "+")
       {
           CurrentID += InputString.Substring(i, 1);
       }
       else
       {
          AllIDs.Add(CurrentID);
          CurrentID = string.Empty;
       }
 }
 string[] SeparatedIDs = AllIDs.ToArray();
```

Even though this does work it just seems overly complicated for what i'm trying to do.
Is there an easier way to split strings or cleaner ?

Comment: Note that storing collection of IDs as set of rows will likely be better solution, but it is not an answer to how to use `String.Split` and `String.Join` methods.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes i've also seen posts about how this is better, as first touched any programming language a week ago, and mysql is a second one ontop i have to use, I wasn't really comfortable changing anything. My main concern would be it looking unorganized in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to use the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms131448.aspx) method with [StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx). `RemoveEmptyEntries` helps you to avoid empty string as the last array element.

Example:

```
char[] delimeters = new[] { '+' };
string InputString = "5+6+12+33+1+9+";
string[] SeparatedIDs = InputString.Split(delimeters, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string SeparatedID in SeparatedIDs)
    Console.WriteLine(SeparatedID);
```

Comment: the array of char isnt needed - that overload is declared as params

Comment: Would changing (new[] { '+' }, to (new[] { '+','-' }, allow me to split at both + and - ? just curious as it does not apply to my current project.

Comment: `BornToGrill` you can split on as many delimiters in your case as long as each is separated by a `,` nad is surround by it's own `''`

Comment: @BornToGrill, agree with DJ KRAZE, you can use any set of delimeters.

Comment: Alright thanks! I'll give you the best answer as it does the job in a much more clean manner, and has more versatility than the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
var result = InputString.Split(new char[] { '+' });
```

You can use other overloads of [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131450(v=vs.110).aspx)
as well if you want to remove empty spaces.

Comment: Brilliant ! Thanks for the insanely quick response. This'll cut my code down by quiet a bit and make it much sleeker.

Answer (score 0):

`string[] IDs = InputString.Split('+');` will split your `InputString` into an array of strings using the `+` character

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = InputString.Split('+', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

extra options needed since there is a trailing +